# matplotlibrc and latex package setup

Tags: python, matplotlib, configuration, latex, configuration-files

How do I set latex package options in python?

I am trying to setup siunitx. I don't understand how to set options. This also applies to the `matplotlibrc` directly.
The following does not work.

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rc('text', usetex=True)
mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = '\usepackage[range-units = single,range-phrase={-}]{siunitx}'
## using the following instead of the previous line works...
# mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = '\usepackage[range-units = single]{siunitx},\sisetup{range-phrase={-}}'

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(1,100,1)
y=x
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y,label=r'\SIrange{0}{1}{\metre\per\second}')
ax.legend(loc=0)
```

Since the code snippet works, I would suggest that it is due to the use of the comma. I tried `\,` or `','` without luck. I tried it on Mac in a `jupyter notebook`.
In the default `matplotlibrc` it says

```
#text.latex.preamble :      ## IMPROPER USE OF THIS FEATURE WILL LEAD TO LATEX FAILURES
                            ## AND IS THEREFORE UNSUPPORTED. PLEASE DO NOT ASK FOR HELP
                            ## IF THIS FEATURE DOES NOT DO WHAT YOU EXPECT IT TO.
                            ## preamble is a comma separated list of LaTeX statements
                            ## that are included in the LaTeX document preamble.
                            ## An example:
                            ## text.latex.preamble : \usepackage{bm},\usepackage{euler}
                            ## The following packages are always loaded with usetex, so
                            ## beware of package collisions: color, geometry, graphicx,
                            ## type1cm, textcomp. Adobe Postscript (PSSNFS) font packages
                            ## may also be loaded, depending on your font settings
```

Unfortunately I cannot find any information on the proper usage of this option besides what is specified in the comments...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that it helps to enclose the preamble string in a list.

```
mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = ['\usepackage[range-units=single,range-phrase={-}]{siunitx}']
```

Comment: Strangely, this works in the notebook itself but not via the `matplotlibrc`. Any idea what might be needed for specifying it directly in the file?

Comment: Not at the moment. What does "not work" actually mean here? Is there a latex error or a python error or is it simply not applied? I do not have this latex package available, is there a more standard package that can be used for testing?

Comment: It results in the two `RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string: '$1.0$'`. Unfortunately I cannot think of a 'more' standard package to use with python where I also need a configuration.